# Open SaveAs dialog box to save file in local directory in client side javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer, legacy-code

Edit this question to narrow down my tasks:

I want to open a saveAs dialog box on click on a button and let user to save file in local directory.

Solution should be in client side javascript and can use external library if it supports Chrome, Edge browsers.

For instance, when i click on button, it should pop this screen:

[image]

Comment: Java has native support for Base64 encoding.

Comment: @KJ something tells me there is more to this story.

Comment: @hfontanez - Correct, i can do the decoding. Lets suppose i have a decoded string in the JS. Now i am looking to convert to PDF using the decoding string in plain javascript.

Comment: @KJ - I am already using the polyfill. It gives me the flexibility of using atob and btoa functions that i can't use in plain javascript. Now, i can do the encode to binay using atob. After that i have to convert it to the blob object for showing on the UI. Everytime i am using Blob it says IE not supported.

Comment: @KJ what do you suggest? Is there an possibility if i can do any conversion in java and then send some form of string to JS for the pdf? I mean I don't know just thinking the alternatives. As this is the requirement and has to do this.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for letting me know. I didn't know that IE does not support pdf. Can we do one thing, on click of a button from the UI if we can pop up a window that let's user to save the pdf file in directory. Once file is saved, then user can use acrobat reader to open that file.

So, we still have base64 encoded string in JS, and instead of opening it directly we can now popup a window and lets user save the file.  Can you help me to accomplish this task?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240176/discussion-between-ranjit-singh-and-k-j).

Comment: @KJ i came up with an idea. What if i save a pdf file on s3 and return the path of the file and then on client side, i will open it path in iframe? What's your thought?

Comment: Ranjit, it appears to me you want to code your own PDF writer using your own implementation (no libraries). If this is true, you will have to know the PDF specification beginning to end. Your end product will have to open and be "readable" by PDF file readers. To my knowledge, no browser can create PDF files from scratch; plugin or not. I know of plugins that can edit. This means your source is already a PDF file. Assuming I am wrong, you need code to interact with these plugins. That means the plugin creators must provide some API you can call. I don't know of one that does that.

Comment: Coding from scratch a PDF writer is not a trivial task. I used iText library in the past to create PDF files and even that was confusing enough.